# Button in ascx , loop via query, send parameter or identify uniquely

Tags: asp.net, ascx

In most languages for the web, it's a simple 3 line process.

php for example.

```
<?php foreach (x in y) {?>
  <td><a href="">my button #<?php echo ++i;?></a></td>
<? } ?>
```

Not in `ASP`. Apparently I need to program artificial intelligence for a lunar mission to loop a query and output a unique button. Apologies for the sarcasm, I am frustrated extensively.

Here is my code, which does not do what I need. Am I missing an simple option that won't take an hour to code?

```
<% using (SqlDataReader reader=Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(Config.GetConnectionString(),CommandType.Text,"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[table] WHERE bHasBeenProcessed IS NULL")) { %>
                    <% while (reader.Read()) { %>

                        <tr>
                            <td><%=reader["Name"].ToString()%></td>
                            <td><%=reader["Email"].ToString()%></td>
                            <td><%=reader["datestamp"].ToString()%></td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button CommandName='<%#reader["id"].ToString()%>' id="cmdSave" text='Process It' OnClick="HandlerFunction" runat="server" cssclass="dnnPrimaryAction" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                <% }} %>
```

I find it ridiculous that I have to use CommandName/Argument in the first place.
People say "you can't mix server side and client side code". Well I'm not, right?
The entirety of that snippet is produced server-side.
It queries the database, loops over the records, and outputs a table. Which works great.
But the CommandName refuses to process my variable.
So I have NO way of identifying which row was clicked.

Comment: You're doing several things wrong in your example: you're using WebForms (with ASP.NET "WebControls") as though it's like PHP when the two have very different paradigms. You're also mixing view-level logic (outputing to the client) with business-logic (the database call). You also aren't HTML-encoding your output which means your code is vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Comment: It's a dirty quick script intended for a short period of time usage by administrators who have access via the DNN platform explicitly.
So security is not concern, time spent producing a simple page with simple buttons in a simple loop, is.  
Do I really need to jump through 50 hoops to do a simple task like this? 
Ignoring the fact that it is poor code, and the morality involved there.

The code above operates fundamentally because server side it is processing the loop and outputting. Is it really that much of a stretch to put a dynamic value into a text property? Seriously.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP.  If you re-tag you're more likely to get the results you're after.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I coded href's with URL parameters and process it that way instead via POST.
Ridiculous.  Problem solved.

Definitely welcome any suggestions on how to **quickly** do this, whether that be correct or incorrect methodology.